# Jquery : Find checkboxes under dynamic class

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

i have a dynamic form where below is the strucutre

1. `is_required`  class is added to parent class
2. `checkboxes_required`  does wrap all the checkboxes under is_required as below

   ```
      <div class="form-group is_required">
      <label>your interestes</label><br>
      <div class="checkboxes_required">
         <input type="checkbox" name="your_interestes[]" value="Games">Games 
         <input type="checkbox" name="your_interestes[]" value="study">study 
         <input type="checkbox" name="your_interestes[]" value="programming">programming
         <input type="checkbox" name="your_interestes[]" value="work">work
      </div>
   </div>
   ```

i can loop on is_required and then find checkboxes_required as below but dont know how can pass this as as selector to further loop on checkboxes

```
 $(".is_required").each(function() {
        var element = $(this);          
        $(element).children().each(function () {
             if($(this).hasClass("checkboxes_required")){
            var checkboxElement = $(this);//here i have access to the div holding checkboxes 
     }
   }
```

Below code loops on the checkboxes to but i am not sure how do i pass the selector to this

```
$($("selector here ", checkboxElement).each(function(e){
  console.log(e);
  if($(this).is(":checked")){
     console.log(boolcount+"true");
  }
else {
  console.log(boolcount+"flase");
  }
})
```

Comment: Hello there!
Did you check my answer?
If you found it useful please consider upvoting it and/or choosing it as final answer.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you access the required checkboxes directly?

Here's a simple example to understand what I suggest, it just checks them automatically:

```
$(".checkboxes_required").each(function() {
     $(this).children().each(function () {
           $(this).attr("checked", true);
     });
});
```

You can use the same logic to do other manipulation (just took your example code as start):

```
var checkedCount = 0;
var uncheckedCount = 0;
$(".checkboxes_required").each(function () {
    $(this).children().each(function () {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            checkedCount++;
        } else {
            uncheckedCount++;
        }
    });
});
console.log("A total of " + checkedCount + " checked");
console.log("and of " + uncheckedCount + " unchecked");
```

Comment: Hi there,

if you found my code useful please don't forget upvoting it and/or choosing it as final answer.